# How to push Node-Red to GitHub without revealing sensitive information?

Tags: security, github, credentials, node-red, password-protection

I would like to share my NodeRed Code in Github as part of an IOT project, however I would like to keep some of my data private (wifi password, database password, etc).

I could manually erase this information, but this would not be very practical, since I would have to do it every time I update the file.

In my python scripts I use os.environ.get to save my passwords and upload to GitHub securely.

¿Is there some way to set up Node-Red to easily push to GitHub without revealing sensitive information?

Comment: make a .gitignore file and add .env and other non-tracking files?

Comment: But then how do you setup Node Red to pull credentials from the .env files?

Comment: [run with `--env-file` option](https://binnes.github.io/Node-RED-container-prod/Node-RED-config-from-environment/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node properties can be pulled from environment variables using the `${}` syntax. This is implemented by the runtime so should work in all nodes. If the node uses the typed input widget then they should also support environment variables directly.

Details are in the documentation here: https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables

Secondly any node options that are explicitly tagged as credentials are stored in a separate encrypted file `_creds.json`. By default this is encrypted in a randomly generated key on first run and stored in a hidden file in the userDir, but you can set your own key in the `settings.js` file.

If you use the **Projects** feature to store your flows in a git repository then you will be prompted for the encryption key needed as part of setting up the project or when you check it out. Documentation for projects is here:
https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/projects/